# RxJava: How to convert List of objects to List of another objects

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have the List of SourceObjects and I need to convert it to the List of ResultObjects.

I can fetch one object to another using method of ResultObject:

```
convertFromSource(srcObj);
```

of course I can do it like this:

```
public void onNext(List<SourceObject> srcObjects) {
   List<ResultsObject> resObjects = new ArrayList<>();
   for (SourceObject srcObj : srcObjects) {
       resObjects.add(new ResultsObject().convertFromSource(srcObj));
   }
}
```

but I will be very appreciate to someone who can show how to do the same using **rxJava**.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

If your `Observable` emits a `List`, you can use these operators:

- `flatMapIterable` (transform your list to an Observable of items)
- `map` (transform your item to another item)
- `toList` operators (transform a completed Observable to a Observable which emit a list of items from the completed Observable)

  ```
  Observable<SourceObjet> source = ...
  source.flatMapIterable(list -> list)
        .map(item -> new ResultsObject().convertFromSource(item))
        .toList()
        .subscribe(transformedList -> ...);
  ```

Comment: This looks really clean, though has some disadvantages. 1. If source emits more than one list, they are all going to flattened by `flatMapIterable` into a single stream of objects and `toList()` will collect them in a single list. So if you care about multiple emissions and keeping them in separate lists, then unfortunately you lose this. 2. `toList()` waits for the source observable to complete, so if you do that on an infinite observable (like one bound to UI events), you will never get anything in your `subscribe()`.

Comment: @MarcinKoziński how would you solve nr. 2? I am having the situation where .toList does not return anything. Thanks

Comment: I think you just need to use a different approach. If you're trying to transform each element of a list, you might have to just do `.map(list -> /* build a new list using plain old for loop */)`. Or use any other approach to transform your list inside the `.map()`. Otherwise you could use operators like `.take(itemCount)` on your infinite observable to make it finite. Note that this obviously drops all elements after `itemCount`, so that might not be what you want.

Comment: "some disadvantages" - rather, I'd say this is almost always not what is wanted.  This answer should be down-voted and Noel's answer should be upvoted.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, for the jargon free explanation. Super helpful.

Answer (score 73):

If you want to maintain the `Lists` emitted by the source `Observable` but convert the contents, i.e. `Observable<List<SourceObject>>` to `Observable<List<ResultsObject>>`, you can do something like this:

```
Observable<List<SourceObject>> source = ...
source.flatMap(list ->
        Observable.fromIterable(list)
            .map(item -> new ResultsObject().convertFromSource(item))
            .toList()
            .toObservable() // Required for RxJava 2.x
    )
    .subscribe(resultsList -> ...);
```

This ensures a couple of things:

- The number of `Lists` emitted by the `Observable` is maintained. i.e. if the source emits 3 lists, there will be 3 transformed lists on the other end
- Using `Observable.fromIterable()` will ensure the inner `Observable` terminates so that `toList()` can be used

Answer (score 11):

The [Observable.from()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/from.html) factory method allows you to convert a collection of objects into an Observable stream. Once you have a stream you can use the [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) operator to transform each emitted item. Finally, you will have to subscribe to the resulting Observable in order to use the transformed items:

```
// Assuming List<SourceObject> srcObjects
Observable<ResultsObject> resultsObjectObservable = Observable.from(srcObjects).map(new Func1<SourceObject, ResultsObject>() {
    @Override
    public ResultsObject call(SourceObject srcObj) {
        return new ResultsObject().convertFromSource(srcObj);
    }
});

resultsObjectObservable.subscribe(new Action1<ResultsObject>() { // at this point is where the transformation will start
    @Override
    public void call(ResultsObject resultsObject) { // this method will be called after each item has been transformed
        // use each transformed item
    }
});
```

The abbreviated version if you use lambdas would look like this:

```
Observable.from(srcObjects)
  .map(srcObj -> new ResultsObject().convertFromSource(srcObj))
  .subscribe(resultsObject -> ...);
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't break the chain, just like this.

```
Observable.from(Arrays.asList(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", }))
.map(s -> Integer.valueOf(s))
.reduce(new ArrayList<Integer>, (list, s) -> {
    list.add(s);
    return list;
})
.subscribe(i -> {
    // Do some thing with 'i', it's a list of Integer.
});
```

Comment: Instead of `reduce` you could use `toList()` for a cleaner code.

Comment: Actually there are problems with `toList` like described in this comment above. reduce solves them
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734060/rxjava-how-to-convert-list-of-objects-to-list-of-another-objects#comment62270275_35750170

Comment: Nope. My comment is not true. :) The same problems are also with `reduce` because `reduce` also waits for completion.

Answer (score 2):

Non blocking conversion using nested map function

```
val ints: Observable<List<Int>> = Observable.fromArray(listOf(1, 2, 3))

val strings: Observable<List<String>> = ints.map { list -> list.map { it.toString() } }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [map](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/map.html) operator. For example if you have list**s** of integers and you want to convert to list**s** of doubles:

```
    List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>();
    Observable.just(integers).map(values -> {
        List<Double> doubles = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for(Integer i: values) {
            doubles.add(i.doubleValue());
        }
        return doubles;
    });
```

But all it's a lot more natural if you can control the observable and change it to observe single elements instead of collections. Same code that converts single integer elements into double ones:

```
Observable.just(1,2,3).map(element -> element.doubleValue())
```

Comment: Wouldn't `just(li)` emit a single item (the list), not every element from the list like `from(li)`?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, but as my understand of the problem Yura wants to emit lists no elements of the list (It uses onNext(List)). As I said in my response it's not the more natural, but sometimes can be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As an extension to [Noel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42055221/3129644) great answer. 
Let's say transformation also depends on some server data that might change during subscription. In that case use **flatMap** + **scan**.

As a result when id list changes, transformations will restart anew. And when server data changes related to a specific id, single item will be retransformed as well.

```
fun getFarmsWithGroves(): Observable<List<FarmWithGroves>> {

        return subscribeForIds() //may change during subscription
                .switchMap { idList: Set<String> ->

                    Observable.fromIterable(idList)
                            .flatMap { id: String -> transformId(id) } //may change during subscription
                            .scan(emptyList<FarmWithGroves>()) { collector: List<FarmWithGroves>, candidate: FarmWithGroves ->
                                updateList(collector, candidate)
                            }
                }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using toList() waits for the source observable to complete, so if you do that on an infinite observable (like one bound to UI events and Database calls), you will never get anything in your subscribe().

The solution to that is to Use **FlatMapSingle** or **SwitchMapSingle**.

```
Observable<List<Note>> observable =   noteDao.getAllNotes().flatMapSingle(list -> Observable.fromIterable(list).toList());
```

**Now,everytime your list is updated, you can make that event behave as an observable.**

Answer (score 0):

If what you need is simply `List<A>` to `List<B>` without manipulating result of `List<B>`.

The cleanest version is:

```
List<A> a = ... // ["1", "2", ..]
List<B> b = Observable.from(a)
                      .map(a -> new B(a))
                      .toList()
                      .toBlocking()
                      .single();
```