# Convert one type of list to another RXJava? (Javascript map equivalent)

Tags: javascript, rx-java

Lets say I have an observable 
`Observable<List<A>>` and I want to convert it to an Observable as `Observable<List<B>>`. Is there any best possible way to convert `List<A>` into `List<B>`. Javascript's `map`'s like implementation would be the ideal situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Observable.from(Iterable<A>)` to get `Observable<A>`, map it (A => B), and convert to `List<B>` with `Observable.toList()`

```
Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
.map(val -> mapIntToString(val)).toList()
```

E.g.

```
  Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))
.map(val -> val + "mapped").toList()
.toBlocking().subscribe(System.out::println);
```

yields

> [1mapped, 2mapped, 3mapped]

Answer (score 5):

I answered another similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42055221/454449

I've copied the answer here for convenience (not sure if that goes against the rules):

If you want to maintain the `Lists` emitted by the source `Observable` but convert the contents, i.e. `Observable<List<SourceObject>>` to `Observable<List<ResultsObject>>`, you can do something like this:

```
Observable<List<SourceObject>> source = ...
source.flatMap(list ->
        Observable.fromIterable(list)
            .map(item -> new ResultsObject(item))
            .toList()
            .toObservable() // Required for RxJava 2.x
    )
    .subscribe(resultsList -> ...);
```

This ensures a couple of things:

- The number of `Lists` emitted by the `Observable` is maintained. i.e. if the source emits 3 lists, there will be 3 transformed lists on the other end
- Using `Observable.fromIterable()` will ensure the inner `Observable` terminates so that `toList()` can be used

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **compose** which will get an observable and will return a different.

```
Observable.Transformer<Integer, String> transformIntegerToString() {
    return observable -> observable.map(String::valueOf);
   }


  @Test
public void observableWithTransformToString() {
    Observable.from(Arrays.asList(1,2,3))
              .map(number -> {
                  System.out.println("Item is Integer:" + Integer.class.isInstance(number));
                  return number;
              })
              .compose(transformIntegerToString())
              .subscribe(number -> System.out.println("Item is String:" + (String.class.isInstance(number))));

}
```

You can see more examples here

https://github.com/politrons/reactive